# while loop php timeout

Tags: php, api

Olá, preciso fazer uma verificação periódica em uma lista com mais de 4000 ids para fazer uma verificação e enviar para o banco de dados, recebo os dados via API e faço um while para fazer as verificações.

qual seria a melhor maneira de tratar esse tipo de laço para nao retornar um timeout, pois dentro desse while preciso chamar a api novamente para cada id e verificar os dados, nos teste que fiz, todas as vezes nao consegui concluir por retornou timeout.

Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Você pode executar o PHP pelo terminal. Caso você queira executar pelo navegador e aguardar o resultado para exibir na tela, você pode executar o script pelo terminal e fica verificando se ele já terminou de executar para dar um retorno.

Answer (score -2):

Olá, verifica o tempo de resposta da `API` que você está consumindo. Depois vai no `php` e configura o `timeout` maior(conforme a necessidade)!

Configurar o `timeout`:

```
set_time_limit(120); direto no código, no início do arquivo
```

Configurar o `timeout` no php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 120
```

E também tem a possibilidade de remover `timeout` (Possa ser que não funcione por questão de segurança):

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Você está usando `CURL` para consumir à `API`?

Se tiver usando o `CURL`:

```
$segundos = 10;//conforme a necessidade
...
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $segundos);
...
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, isso verifiquei mesmo assim continuo com o erro, um colega de outro grupo me sugeriu usar por paginação o consumo desta API, estou procurando algo sobre mas ate o momento encontrei algo relevante, nunca usei api com paginação.

Comment: Certo, verificar na documentação da api se ela tem suporte a paginação. Ela é uma api privada, com autenticação?

Comment: Sim é privada! Consegui, fiz isto mesmo, usei com a paginação e processo em background, rodou sem problemas, obrigado!